# Как указать переменную в embed

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
dsf.add_field (name = 'lvl', value = vls)
```

- не работает.
  Надо сделать так, чтобы выводилась в embed переменная vls. Как это можно реализовать.

Answer (score 2):

Вы не показали код полностью и не продемонстрировали что вы хотите вывести в переменной vls

```
#инициализация embed, это основа используется всегда
dsf = discord.Embed(title='text', description="text")

#Ваша строка
dsf.add_field(name='текст', value='ваша переменная')

#Непосредственно вывод embed, возможно у вас это отсутствовало
await ctx.send(embed=dsf)
```

Переменная ctx передается как аргумент функции, не могу об этом говорить так как вы не продемонстрировали весь код

Comment: Если он напишет так как вы написали, то он вместо значения(то что хранится в `vls`) ему выведет vls как текст

Comment: Я предположил что ошибка была в выводе самого сообщение через await ctx.send(embed=dsf)

Answer (score 2):

```
dsf.add_field (name = 'lvl', value = f'{vls}')
```

Так вы сможете вывести вашу переменную `vls`